# AWK - Extracting information through using another file - Syntax error

Tags: awk

I am trying to extract information from a file using awk.

The informationfile.txt is similar to:

```
>ENST00000342992.10 cdna:known chromosome:GRCh38:2:178525989:178807421:-1 gene:ENSG00000155657.24 gene_biotype:protein_coding transcript_biotype:protein_coding gene_symbol:TTN description:titin [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:12403]
GCAGTCGTGCATTCCCAGCCTCGCCTCGGGTGTAGGGATTGCATAGAAAAGCAAAACTAC
ACAGTCTTGACTGTGTAGTTTTGTTTTTAGGATTAGAGGCTCACCGATTCATGTCGGAGA
TGGTCAGAAAAACCAACTCTCCATAGGACGTCGTTTCAGAAGCAACCTTGGGCTTAGTCC
CACCCTTTTTAGGCACTCTTGAGAAATCAGAGTGCCTAGAAAGATGACAACTCAAGCACC
GACGTTTACGCAGCCGTTACAAAGCGTTGTGGTACTGGAGGGTAGTACCGCAACCTTTGA
GGCTCACATTAGTGGTTTTCCAGTTCCTGAGGTGAGCTGGTTTAGGGATGGCCAGGTGAT
TTCCACTTCCACTCTGCCCGGCGTGCAGATCTCCTTTAGCGATGGCCGCGCTAAACTGAC
GATCCCCGCCGTGACTAAAGCCAACAGTGGACGATATTCCCTGAAAGCCACCAATGGATC
TGGACAAGCGACTAGTACTGCTGAGCTTCTCGTGAAAGCTGAGACAGCACCACCCAACTT
CGTTCAACGACTGCAGAGCATGACCGTGAGACAAGGAAGCCAAGTGAGACTCCAAGTGAG
AGTGACTGGAATCCCTACACCTGTGGTGAAGTTCTACCGGGATGGAGCCGAAATCCAGAG
CTCCCTTGATTTCCAAATTTCACAAGAAGGCGACCTCTACAGCTTACTGATTGCAGAAGC
ATACCCTGAGGACTCAGGGACCTATTCAGTAAATGCCACCAATAGCGTTGGAAGAGCTAC
TTCGACTGCTGAATTACTGGTTCAAGGTGAAGAAGAAGTACCTGCTAAAAAGACAAAGAC
AATTGTTTCGACTGCTCAGATCTCAGAATCAAGACAAACCCGAATTGAAAAGAAGATTGA
AGCCCACTTTGATGCCAGATCAATTGCAACAGTTGAGATGGTCATAGATGGTGCCGCTGG
GCAACAGCTGCCACATAAAACACCTCCCAGGATTCCTCCGAAGCCAAAGTCAAGATCCCC
AACACCACCGTCTATTGCTGCCAAAGCACAGCTGGCTCGGCAGCAGTCCCCATCGCCCAT
AAGACACTCCCCTTCCCCGGTCAGACACGTGCGGGCACCGACCCCATCTCCGGTCAGGTC
CGTGTCTCCAGCAGCAAGAATCTCCACATCCCCCATCAGGTCTGTTAGGTCTCCATTGCT
CATGCGTAAGACTCAGGCATCCACCGTGGCCACAGGTCCTGAAGTGCCTCCCCCTTGGAA
GCAAGAGGGCTACGTGGCCTCCTCATCTGAGGCTGAGATGAGAGAGACAACGCTGACAAC
CTCTACTCAGATCAGGACAGAAGAGAGATGGGAAGGGAGATACGGTGTCCAGGAGCAAGT
GACCATCAGTGGTGCTGCGGGTGCTGCCGCCAGTGTGTCGGCCAGTGCTAGCTACGCAGC
AGAGGCTGTTGCCACTGGTGCTAAAGAGGTGAAACAAGATGCTGACAAAAGTGCAGCTGT
TGCGACTGTTGTTGCTGCCGTTGATATGGCCAGAGTGAGAGAACCAGTGATCAGCGCTGT
AGAGCAGACTGCTCAGAGGACAACCACGACTGCTGTGCACATCCAACCTGCTCAAGAACA
GGTAAGAAAGGAAGCGGAGAAGACTGCTGTAACTAAGGTAGTAGTGGCCGCCGATAAAGC
CAAGGAACAAGAATTAAAATCAAGAACCAAAGAAGTAATTACCACAAAGCAAGAGCAGAT
GCACGTAACTCATGAGCAGATAAGAAAAGAAACTGAAAAAACATTTGTACCAAAGGTAGT
AATTTCCGCAGCTAAAGCCAAAGAACAAGAAACTAGAATTTCTGAAGAAATTACTAAGAA
ACAGAAACAAGTAACTCAAGAAGCAATAAGACAGGAAACTGAGATAACTGCTGCATCCAT
GGTGGTAGTTGCCACTGCAAAGTCCACAAAACTAGAAACAGTCCCGGGAGCTCAAGAAGA
AACTACCACACAACAAGATCAAATGCACCTAAGTTATGAAAAGATAATGAAGGAAACTAG
GAAAACAGTTGTACCTAAAGTCATAGTTGCCACACCCAAAGTCAAAGAACAAGATTTAGT
>ENST00000460472.6 cdna:known chromosome:GRCh38:2:178525989:178807423:-1 gene:ENSG00000155657.24 gene_biotype:protein_coding transcript_biotype:protein_coding gene_symbol:TTN description:titin [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:12403]
GCAGTCGTGCATTCCCAGCCTCGCCTCGGGTGTAGGGATTGCATAGAAAAGCAAAACTAC
ACAGTCTTGACTGTGTAGTTTTGTTTTTAGGATTAGAGGCTCACCGATTCATGTCGGAGA
TGGTCAGAAAAACCAACTCTCCATAGGACGTCGTTTCAGAAGCAACCTTGGGCTTAGTCC
CACCCTTTTTAGGCACTCTTGAGAAATCAGAGTGCCTAGAAAGATGACAACTCAAGCACC
GACGTTTACGCAGCCGTTACAAAGCGTTGTGGTACTGGAGGGTAGTACCGCAACCTTTGA
GGCTCACATTAGTGGTTTTCCAGTTCCTGAGGTGAGCTGGTTTAGGGATGGCCAGGTGAT
TTCCACTTCCACTCTGCCCGGCGTGCAGATCTCCTTTAGCGATGGCCGCGCTAAACTGAC
GATCCCCGCCGTGACTAAAGCCAACAGTGGACGATATTCCCTGAAAGCCACCAATGGATC
TGGACAAGCGACTAGTACTGCTGAGCTTCTCGTGAAAGCTGAGACAGCACCACCCAACTT
CGTTCAACGACTGCAGAGCATGACCGTGAGACAAGGAAGCCAAGTGAGACTCCAAGTGAG
AGTGACTGGAATCCCTACACCTGTGGTGAAGTTCTACCGGGATGGAGCCGAAATCCAGAG
CTCCCTTGATTTCCAAATTTCACAAGAAGGCGACCTCTACAGCTTACTGATTGCAGAAGC
ATACCCTGAGGACTCAGGGACCTATTCAGTAAATGCCACCAATAGCGTTGGAAGAGCTAC
TTCGACTGCTGAATTACTGGTTCAAGGTGAAGAAGAAGTACCTGCTAAAAAGACAAAGAC
AATTGTTTCGACTGCTCAGATCTCAGAATCAAGACAAACCCGAATTGAAAAGAAGATTGA
AGCCCACTTTGATGCCAGATCAATTGCAACAGTTGAGATGGTCATAGATGGTGCCGCTGG
GCAACAGCTGCCACATAAAACACCTCCCAGGATTCCTCCGAAGCCAAAGTCAAGATCCCC
AACACCACCGTCTATTGCTGCCAAAGCACAGCTGGCTCGGCAGCAGTCCCCATCGCCCAT
AAGACACTCCCCTTCCCCGGTCAGACACGTGCGGGCACCGACCCCATCTCCGGTCAGGTC
CGTGTCTCCAGCAGCAAGAATCTCCACATCCCCCATCAGGTCTGTTAGGTCTCCATTGCT
CATGCGTAAGACTCAGGCATCCACCGTGGCCACAGGTCCTGAAGTGCCTCCCCCTTGGAA
GCAAGAGGGCTACGTGGCCTCCTCATCTGAGGCTGAGATGAGAGAGACAACGCTGACAAC
CTCTACTCAGATCAGGACAGAAGAGAGATGGGAAGGGAGATACGGTGTCCAGGAGCAAGT
GACCATCAGTGGTGCTGCGGGTGCTGCCGCCAGTGTGTCGGCCAGTGCTAGCTACGCAGC
AGAGGCTGTTGCCACTGGTGCTAAAGAGGTGAAACAAGATGCTGACAAAAGTGCAGCTGT
TGCGACTGTTGTTGCTGCCGTTGATATGGCCAGAGTGAGAGAACCAGTGATCAGCGCTGT
AGAGCAGACTGCTCAGAGGACAACCACGACTGCTGTGCACATCCAACCTGCTCAAGAACA
GGTAAGAAAGGAAGCGGAGAAGACTGCTGTAACTAAGGTAGTAGTGGCCGCCGATAAAGC
CAAGGAACAAGAATTAAAATCAAGAACCAAAGAAGTAATTACCACAAAGCAAGAGCAGAT
GCACGTAACTCATGAGCAGATAAGAAAAGAAACTGAAAAAACATTTGTACCAAAGGTAGT
AATTTCCGCAGCTAAAGCCAAAGAACAAGAAACTAGAATTTCTGAAGAAATTACTAAGAA
ACAGAAACAAGTAACTCAAGAAGCAATAAGACAGGAAACTGAGATAACTGCTGCATCCAT
GGTGGTAGTTGCCACTGCAAAGTCCACAAAACTAGAAACAGTCCCGGGAGCTCAAGAAGA
AACTACCACACAACAAGATCAAATGCACCTAAGTTATGAAAAGATAATGAAGGAAACTAG
GAAAACAGTTGTACCTAAAGTCATAGTTGCCACACCCAAAGTCAAAGAACAAGATTTAGT
>ENST00000589042.5 cdna:known chromosome:GRCh38:2:178525989:178807423:-1 gene:ENSG00000155657.24 gene_biotype:protein_coding transcript_biotype:protein_coding gene_symbol:TTN description:titin [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:12403]
GCAGTCGTGCATTCCCAGCCTCGCCTCGGGTGTAGGGATTGCATAGAAAAGCAAAACTAC
ACAGTCTTGACTGTGTAGTTTTGTTTTTAGGATTAGAGGCTCACCGATTCATGTCGGAGA
TGGTCAGAAAAACCAACTCTCCATAGGACGTCGTTTCAGAAGCAACCTTGGGCTTAGTCC
CACCCTTTTTAGGCACTCTTGAGAAATCAGAGTGCCTAGAAAGATGACAACTCAAGCACC
GACGTTTACGCAGCCGTTACAAAGCGTTGTGGTACTGGAGGGTAGTACCGCAACCTTTGA
GGCTCACATTAGTGGTTTTCCAGTTCCTGAGGTGAGCTGGTTTAGGGATGGCCAGGTGAT
TTCCACTTCCACTCTGCCCGGCGTGCAGATCTCCTTTAGCGATGGCCGCGCTAAACTGAC
GATCCCCGCCGTGACTAAAGCCAACAGTGGACGATATTCCCTGAAAGCCACCAATGGATC
TGGACAAGCGACTAGTACTGCTGAGCTTCTCGTGAAAGCTGAGACAGCACCACCCAACTT
CGTTCAACGACTGCAGAGCATGACCGTGAGACAAGGAAGCCAAGTGAGACTCCAAGTGAG
AGTGACTGGAATCCCTACACCTGTGGTGAAGTTCTACCGGGATGGAGCCGAAATCCAGAG
CTCCCTTGATTTCCAAATTTCACAAGAAGGCGACCTCTACAGCTTACTGATTGCAGAAGC
ATACCCTGAGGACTCAGGGACCTATTCAGTAAATGCCACCAATAGCGTTGGAAGAGCTAC
TTCGACTGCTGAATTACTGGTTCAAGGTGAAGAAGAAGTACCTGCTAAAAAGACAAAGAC
AATTGTTTCGACTGCTCAGATCTCAGAATCAAGACAAACCCGAATTGAAAAGAAGATTGA
AGCCCACTTTGATGCCAGATCAATTGCAACAGTTGAGATGGTCATAGATGGTGCCGCTGG
GCAACAGCTGCCACATAAAACACCTCCCAGGATTCCTCCGAAGCCAAAGTCAAGATCCCC
AACACCACCGTCTATTGCTGCCAAAGCACAGCTGGCTCGGCAGCAGTCCCCATCGCCCAT
AAGACACTCCCCTTCCCCGGTCAGACACGTGCGGGCACCGACCCCATCTCCGGTCAGGTC
CGTGTCTCCAGCAGCAAGAATCTCCACATCCCCCATCAGGTCTGTTAGGTCTCCATTGCT
CATGCGTAAGACTCAGGCATCCACCGTGGCCACAGGTCCTGAAGTGCCTCCCCCTTGGAA
GCAAGAGGGCTACGTGGCCTCCTCATCTGAGGCTGAGATGAGAGAGACAACGCTGACAAC
CTCTACTCAGATCAGGACAGAAGAGAGATGGGAAGGGAGATACGGTGTCCAGGAGCAAGT
GACCATCAGTGGTGCTGCGGGTGCTGCCGCCAGTGTGTCGGCCAGTGCTAGCTACGCAGC
AGAGGCTGTTGCCACTGGTGCTAAAGAGGTGAAACAAGATGCTGACAAAAGTGCAGCTGT
TGCGACTGTTGTTGCTGCCGTTGATATGGCCAGAGTGAGAGAACCAGTGATCAGCGCTGT
AGAGCAGACTGCTCAGAGGACAACCACGACTGCTGTGCACATCCAACCTGCTCAAGAACA
GGTAAGAAAGGAAGCGGAGAAGACTGCTGTAACTAAGGTAGTAGTGGCCGCCGATAAAGC
CAAGGAACAAGAATTAAAATCAAGAACCAAAGAAGTAATTACCACAAAGCAAGAGCAGAT
GCACGTAACTCATGAGCAGATAAGAAAAGAAACTGAAAAAACATTTGTACCAAAGGTAGT
AATTTCCGCAGCTAAAGCCAAAGAACAAGAAACTAGAATTTCTGAAGAAATTACTAAGAA
ACAGAAACAAGTAACTCAAGAAGCAATAAGACAGGAAACTGAGATAACTGCTGCATCCAT
GGTGGTAGTTGCCACTGCAAAGTCCACAAAACTAGAAACAGTCCCGGGAGCTCAAGAAGA
AACTACCACACAACAAGATCAAATGCACCTAAGTTATGAAAAGATAATGAAGGAAACTAG
GAAAACAGTTGTACCTAAAGTCATAGTTGCCACACCCAAAGTCAAAGAACAAGATTTAGT
>ENST00000591111.5 cdna:known chromosome:GRCh38:2:178525989:178807423:-1 gene:ENSG00000155657.24 gene_biotype:protein_coding transcript_biotype:protein_coding gene_symbol:TTN description:titin [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:12403]
GCAGTCGTGCATTCCCAGCCTCGCCTCGGGTGTAGGGATTGCATAGAAAAGCAAAACTAC
ACAGTCTTGACTGTGTAGTTTTGTTTTTAGGATTAGAGGCTCACCGATTCATGTCGGAGA
TGGTCAGAAAAACCAACTCTCCATAGGACGTCGTTTCAGAAGCAACCTTGGGCTTAGTCC
CACCCTTTTTAGGCACTCTTGAGAAATCAGAGTGCCTAGAAAGATGACAACTCAAGCACC
GACGTTTACGCAGCCGTTACAAAGCGTTGTGGTACTGGAGGGTAGTACCGCAACCTTTGA
GGCTCACATTAGTGGTTTTCCAGTTCCTGAGGTGAGCTGGTTTAGGGATGGCCAGGTGAT
TTCCACTTCCACTCTGCCCGGCGTGCAGATCTCCTTTAGCGATGGCCGCGCTAAACTGAC
GATCCCCGCCGTGACTAAAGCCAACAGTGGACGATATTCCCTGAAAGCCACCAATGGATC
TGGACAAGCGACTAGTACTGCTGAGCTTCTCGTGAAAGCTGAGACAGCACCACCCAACTT
CGTTCAACGACTGCAGAGCATGACCGTGAGACAAGGAAGCCAAGTGAGACTCCAAGTGAG
AGTGACTGGAATCCCTACACCTGTGGTGAAGTTCTACCGGGATGGAGCCGAAATCCAGAG
CTCCCTTGATTTCCAAATTTCACAAGAAGGCGACCTCTACAGCTTACTGATTGCAGAAGC
ATACCCTGAGGACTCAGGGACCTATTCAGTAAATGCCACCAATAGCGTTGGAAGAGCTAC
TTCGACTGCTGAATTACTGGTTCAAGGTGAAGAAGAAGTACCTGCTAAAAAGACAAAGAC
AATTGTTTCGACTGCTCAGATCTCAGAATCAAGACAAACCCGAATTGAAAAGAAGATTGA
AGCCCACTTTGATGCCAGATCAATTGCAACAGTTGAGATGGTCATAGATGGTGCCGCTGG
GCAACAGCTGCCACATAAAACACCTCCCAGGATTCCTCCGAAGCCAAAGTCAAGATCCCC
AACACCACCGTCTATTGCTGCCAAAGCACAGCTGGCTCGGCAGCAGTCCCCATCGCCCAT
AAGACACTCCCCTTCCCCGGTCAGACACGTGCGGGCACCGACCCCATCTCCGGTCAGGTC
CGTGTCTCCAGCAGCAAGAATCTCCACATCCCCCATCAGGTCTGTTAGGTCTCCATTGCT
CATGCGTAAGACTCAGGCATCCACCGTGGCCACAGGTCCTGAAGTGCCTCCCCCTTGGAA
GCAAGAGGGCTACGTGGCCTCCTCATCTGAGGCTGAGATGAGAGAGACAACGCTGACAAC
CTCTACTCAGATCAGGACAGAAGAGAGATGGGAAGGGAGATACGGTGTCCAGGAGCAAGT
GACCATCAGTGGTGCTGCGGGTGCTGCCGCCAGTGTGTCGGCCAGTGCTAGCTACGCAGC
AGAGGCTGTTGCCACTGGTGCTAAAGAGGTGAAACAAGATGCTGACAAAAGTGCAGCTGT
TGCGACTGTTGTTGCTGCCGTTGATATGGCCAGAGTGAGAGAACCAGTGATCAGCGCTGT
AGAGCAGACTGCTCAGAGGACAACCACGACTGCTGTGCACATCCAACCTGCTCAAGAACA
GGTAAGAAAGGAAGCGGAGAAGACTGCTGTAACTAAGGTAGTAGTGGCCGCCGATAAAGC
CAAGGAACAAGAATTAAAATCAAGAACCAAAGAAGTAATTACCACAAAGCAAGAGCAGAT
GCACGTAACTCATGAGCAGATAAGAAAAGAAACTGAAAAAACATTTGTACCAAAGGTAGT
AATTTCCGCAGCTAAAGCCAAAGAACAAGAAACTAGAATTTCTGAAGAAATTACTAAGAA
ACAGAAACAAGTAACTCAAGAAGCAATAAGACAGGAAACTGAGATAACTGCTGCATCCAT
GGTGGTAGTTGCCACTGCAAAGTCCACAAAACTAGAAACAGTCCCGGGAGCTCAAGAAGA
AACTACCACACAACAAGATCAAATGCACCTAAGTTATGAAAAGATAATGAAGGAAACTAG
GAAAACAGTTGTACCTAAAGTCATAGTTGCCACACCCAAAGTCAAAGAACAAGATTTAGT
>ENST00000425332.2 cdna:known chromosome:GRCh38:2:178663627:178667307:-1 gene:ENSG00000155657.24 gene_biotype:protein_coding transcript_biotype:protein_coding gene_symbol:TTN description:titin [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:12403]
GCAGTCGTGCATTCCCAGCCTCGCCTCGGGTGTAGGGATTGCATAGAAAAGCAAAACTAC
ACAGTCTTGACTGTGTAGTTTTGTTTTTAGGATTAGAGGCTCACCGATTCATGTCGGAGA
TGGTCAGAAAAACCAACTCTCCATAGGACGTCGTTTCAGAAGCAACCTTGGGCTTAGTCC
CACCCTTTTTAGGCACTCTTGAGAAATCAGAGTGCCTAGAAAGATGACAACTCAAGCACC
GACGTTTACGCAGCCGTTACAAAGCGTTGTGGTACTGGAGGGTAGTACCGCAACCTTTGA
GGCTCACATTAGTGGTTTTCCAGTTCCTGAGGTGAGCTGGTTTAGGGATGGCCAGGTGAT
TTCCACTTCCACTCTGCCCGGCGTGCAGATCTCCTTTAGCGATGGCCGCGCTAAACTGAC
GATCCCCGCCGTGACTAAAGCCAACAGTGGACGATATTCCCTGAAAGCCACCAATGGATC
TGGACAAGCGACTAGTACTGCTGAGCTTCTCGTGAAAGCTGAGACAGCACCACCCAACTT
CGTTCAACGACTGCAGAGCATGACCGTGAGACAAGGAAGCCAAGTGAGACTCCAAGTGAG
AGTGACTGGAATCCCTACACCTGTGGTGAAGTTCTACCGGGATGGAGCCGAAATCCAGAG
CTCCCTTGATTTCCAAATTTCACAAGAAGGCGACCTCTACAGCTTACTGATTGCAGAAGC
ATACCCTGAGGACTCAGGGACCTATTCAGTAAATGCCACCAATAGCGTTGGAAGAGCTAC
TTCGACTGCTGAATTACTGGTTCAAGGTGAAGAAGAAGTACCTGCTAAAAAGACAAAGAC
AATTGTTTCGACTGCTCAGATCTCAGAATCAAGACAAACCCGAATTGAAAAGAAGATTGA
AGCCCACTTTGATGCCAGATCAATTGCAACAGTTGAGATGGTCATAGATGGTGCCGCTGG
GCAACAGCTGCCACATAAAACACCTCCCAGGATTCCTCCGAAGCCAAAGTCAAGATCCCC
AACACCACCGTCTATTGCTGCCAAAGCACAGCTGGCTCGGCAGCAGTCCCCATCGCCCAT
AAGACACTCCCCTTCCCCGGTCAGACACGTGCGGGCACCGACCCCATCTCCGGTCAGGTC
CGTGTCTCCAGCAGCAAGAATCTCCACATCCCCCATCAGGTCTGTTAGGTCTCCATTGCT
CATGCGTAAGACTCAGGCATCCACCGTGGCCACAGGTCCTGAAGTGCCTCCCCCTTGGAA
GCAAGAGGGCTACGTGGCCTCCTCATCTGAGGCTGAGATGAGAGAGACAACGCTGACAAC
CTCTACTCAGATCAGGACAGAAGAGAGATGGGAAGGGAGATACGGTGTCCAGGAGCAAGT
GACCATCAGTGGTGCTGCGGGTGCTGCCGCCAGTGTGTCGGCCAGTGCTAGCTACGCAGC
AGAGGCTGTTGCCACTGGTGCTAAAGAGGTGAAACAAGATGCTGACAAAAGTGCAGCTGT
TGCGACTGTTGTTGCTGCCGTTGATATGGCCAGAGTGAGAGAACCAGTGATCAGCGCTGT
AGAGCAGACTGCTCAGAGGACAACCACGACTGCTGTGCACATCCAACCTGCTCAAGAACA
GGTAAGAAAGGAAGCGGAGAAGACTGCTGTAACTAAGGTAGTAGTGGCCGCCGATAAAGC
CAAGGAACAAGAATTAAAATCAAGAACCAAAGAAGTAATTACCACAAAGCAAGAGCAGAT
GCACGTAACTCATGAGCAGATAAGAAAAGAAACTGAAAAAACATTTGTACCAAAGGTAGT
AATTTCCGCAGCTAAAGCCAAAGAACAAGAAACTAGAATTTCTGAAGAAATTACTAAGAA
ACAGAAACAAGTAACTCAAGAAGCAATAAGACAGGAAACTGAGATAACTGCTGCATCCAT
GGTGGTAGTTGCCACTGCAAAGTCCACAAAACTAGAAACAGTCCCGGGAGCTCAAGAAGA
AACTACCACACAACAAGATCAAATGCACCTAAGTTATGAAAAGATAATGAAGGAAACTAG
GAAAACAGTTGTACCTAAAGTCATAGTTGCCACACCCAAAGTCAAAGAACAAGATTTAGT
>ENST00000448510.2 cdna:known chromosome:GRCh38:2:178669625:178672418:-1 gene:ENSG00000155657.24 gene_biotype:protein_coding transcript_biotype:protein_coding gene_symbol:TTN description:titin [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:12403]
GCAGTCGTGCATTCCCAGCCTCGCCTCGGGTGTAGGGATTGCATAGAAAAGCAAAACTAC
ACAGTCTTGACTGTGTAGTTTTGTTTTTAGGATTAGAGGCTCACCGATTCATGTCGGAGA
TGGTCAGAAAAACCAACTCTCCATAGGACGTCGTTTCAGAAGCAACCTTGGGCTTAGTCC
CACCCTTTTTAGGCACTCTTGAGAAATCAGAGTGCCTAGAAAGATGACAACTCAAGCACC
GACGTTTACGCAGCCGTTACAAAGCGTTGTGGTACTGGAGGGTAGTACCGCAACCTTTGA
GGCTCACATTAGTGGTTTTCCAGTTCCTGAGGTGAGCTGGTTTAGGGATGGCCAGGTGAT
TTCCACTTCCACTCTGCCCGGCGTGCAGATCTCCTTTAGCGATGGCCGCGCTAAACTGAC
GATCCCCGCCGTGACTAAAGCCAACAGTGGACGATATTCCCTGAAAGCCACCAATGGATC
TGGACAAGCGACTAGTACTGCTGAGCTTCTCGTGAAAGCTGAGACAGCACCACCCAACTT
CGTTCAACGACTGCAGAGCATGACCGTGAGACAAGGAAGCCAAGTGAGACTCCAAGTGAG
AGTGACTGGAATCCCTACACCTGTGGTGAAGTTCTACCGGGATGGAGCCGAAATCCAGAG
CTCCCTTGATTTCCAAATTTCACAAGAAGGCGACCTCTACAGCTTACTGATTGCAGAAGC
ATACCCTGAGGACTCAGGGACCTATTCAGTAAATGCCACCAATAGCGTTGGAAGAGCTAC
TTCGACTGCTGAATTACTGGTTCAAGGTGAAGAAGAAGTACCTGCTAAAAAGACAAAGAC
AATTGTTTCGACTGCTCAGATCTCAGAATCAAGACAAACCCGAATTGAAAAGAAGATTGA
AGCCCACTTTGATGCCAGATCAATTGCAACAGTTGAGATGGTCATAGATGGTGCCGCTGG
GCAACAGCTGCCACATAAAACACCTCCCAGGATTCCTCCGAAGCCAAAGTCAAGATCCCC
AACACCACCGTCTATTGCTGCCAAAGCACAGCTGGCTCGGCAGCAGTCCCCATCGCCCAT
AAGACACTCCCCTTCCCCGGTCAGACACGTGCGGGCACCGACCCCATCTCCGGTCAGGTC
CGTGTCTCCAGCAGCAAGAATCTCCACATCCCCCATCAGGTCTGTTAGGTCTCCATTGCT
CATGCGTAAGACTCAGGCATCCACCGTGGCCACAGGTCCTGAAGTGCCTCCCCCTTGGAA
GCAAGAGGGCTACGTGGCCTCCTCATCTGAGGCTGAGATGAGAGAGACAACGCTGACAAC
CTCTACTCAGATCAGGACAGAAGAGAGATGGGAAGGGAGATACGGTGTCCAGGAGCAAGT
GACCATCAGTGGTGCTGCGGGTGCTGCCGCCAGTGTGTCGGCCAGTGCTAGCTACGCAGC
AGAGGCTGTTGCCACTGGTGCTAAAGAGGTGAAACAAGATGCTGACAAAAGTGCAGCTGT
TGCGACTGTTGTTGCTGCCGTTGATATGGCCAGAGTGAGAGAACCAGTGATCAGCGCTGT
AGAGCAGACTGCTCAGAGGACAACCACGACTGCTGTGCACATCCAACCTGCTCAAGAACA
GGTAAGAAAGGAAGCGGAGAAGACTGCTGTAACTAAGGTAGTAGTGGCCGCCGATAAAGC
CAAGGAACAAGAATTAAAATCAAGAACCAAAGAAGTAATTACCACAAAGCAAGAGCAGAT
GCACGTAACTCATGAGCAGATAAGAAAAGAAACTGAAAAAACATTTGTACCAAAGGTAGT
AATTTCCGCAGCTAAAGCCAAAGAACAAGAAACTAGAATTTCTGAAGAAATTACTAAGAA
ACAGAAACAAGTAACTCAAGAAGCAATAAGACAGGAAACTGAGATAACTGCTGCATCCAT
GGTGGTAGTTGCCACTGCAAAGTCCACAAAACTAGAAACAGTCCCGGGAGCTCAAGAAGA
AACTACCACACAACAAGATCAAATGCACCTAAGTTATGAAAAGATAATGAAGGAAACTAG
GAAAACAGTTGTACCTAAAGTCATAGTTGCCACACCCAAAGTCAAAGAACAAGATTTAGT
>ENST00000360870.9 cdna:known chromosome:GRCh38:2:178744405:178807421:-1 gene:ENSG00000155657.24 gene_biotype:protein_coding transcript_biotype:protein_coding gene_symbol:TTN description:titin [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:12403]
GCAGTCGTGCATTCCCAGCCTCGCCTCGGGTGTAGGGATTGCATAGAAAAGCAAAACTAC
ACAGTCTTGACTGTGTAGTTTTGTTTTTAGGATTAGAGGCTCACCGATTCATGTCGGAGA
TGGTCAGAAAAACCAACTCTCCATAGGACGTCGTTTCAGAAGCAACCTTGGGCTTAGTCC
CACCCTTTTTAGGCACTCTTGAGAAATCAGAGTGCCTAGAAAGATGACAACTCAAGCACC
GACGTTTACGCAGCCGTTACAAAGCGTTGTGGTACTGGAGGGTAGTACCGCAACCTTTGA
GGCTCACATTAGTGGTTTTCCAGTTCCTGAGGTGAGCTGGTTTAGGGATGGCCAGGTGAT
TTCCACTTCCACTCTGCCCGGCGTGCAGATCTCCTTTAGCGATGGCCGCGCTAAACTGAC
GATCCCCGCCGTGACTAAAGCCAACAGTGGACGATATTCCCTGAAAGCCACCAATGGATC
TGGACAAGCGACTAGTACTGCTGAGCTTCTCGTGAAAGCTGAGACAGCACCACCCAACTT
CGTTCAACGACTGCAGAGCATGACCGTGAGACAAGGAAGCCAAGTGAGACTCCAAGTGAG
AGTGACTGGAATCCCTACACCTGTGGTGAAGTTCTACCGGGATGGAGCCGAAATCCAGAG
CTCCCTTGATTTCCAAATTTCACAAGAAGGCGACCTCTACAGCTTACTGATTGCAGAAGC
ATACCCTGAGGACTCAGGGACCTATTCAGTAAATGCCACCAATAGCGTTGGAAGAGCTAC
TTCGACTGCTGAATTACTGGTTCAAGGTGAAGAAGAAGTACCTGCTAAAAAGACAAAGAC
AATTGTTTCGACTGCTCAGATCTCAGAATCAAGACAAACCCGAATTGAAAAGAAGATTGA
AGCCCACTTTGATGCCAGATCAATTGCAACAGTTGAGATGGTCATAGATGGTGCCGCTGG
GCAACAGCTGCCACATAAAACACCTCCCAGGATTCCTCCGAAGCCAAAGTCAAGATCCCC
AACACCACCGTCTATTGCTGCCAAAGCACAGCTGGCTCGGCAGCAGTCCCCATCGCCCAT
AAGACACTCCCCTTCCCCGGTCAGACACGTGCGGGCACCGACCCCATCTCCGGTCAGGTC
CGTGTCTCCAGCAGCAAGAATCTCCACATCCCCCATCAGGTCTGTTAGGTCTCCATTGCT
CATGCGTAAGACTCAGGCATCCACCGTGGCCACAGGTCCTGAAGTGCCTCCCCCTTGGAA
GCAAGAGGGCTACGTGGCCTCCTCATCTGAGGCTGAGATGAGAGAGACAACGCTGACAAC
CTCTACTCAGATCAGGACAGAAGAGAGATGGGAAGGGAGATACGGTGTCCAGGAGCAAGT
GACCATCAGTGGTGCTGCGGGTGCTGCCGCCAGTGTGTCGGCCAGTGCTAGCTACGCAGC
AGAGGCTGTTGCCACTGGTGCTAAAGAGGTGAAACAAGATGCTGACAAAAGTGCAGCTGT
TGCGACTGTTGTTGCTGCCGTTGATATGGCCAGAGTGAGAGAACCAGTGATCAGCGCTGT
AGAGCAGACTGCTCAGAGGACAACCACGACTGCTGTGCACATCCAACCTGCTCAAGAACA
GGTAAGAAAGGAAGCGGAGAAGACTGCTGTAACTAAGGTAGTAGTGGCCGCCGATAAAGC
CAAGGAACAAGAATTAAAATCAAGAACCAAAGAAGTAATTACCACAAAGCAAGAGCAGAT
GCACGTAACTCATGAGCAGATAAGAAAAGAAACTGAAAAAACATTTGTACCAAAGGTAGT
AATTTCCGCAGCTAAAGCCAAAGAACAAGAAACTAGAATTTCTGAAGAAATTACTAAGAA
ACAGAAACAAGTAACTCAAGAAGCAATAAGACAGGAAACTGAGATAACTGCTGCATCCAT
GGTGGTAGTTGCCACTGCAAAGTCCACAAAACTAGAAACAGTCCCGGGAGCTCAAGAAGA
AACTACCACACAACAAGATCAAATGCACCTAAGTTATGAAAAGATAATGAAGGAAACTAG
GAAAACAGTTGTACCTAAAGTCATAGTTGCCACACCCAAAGTCAAAGAACAAGATTTAGT
>ENST00000634225.1 cdna:known chromosome:GRCh38:2:178753361:178767825:-1 gene:ENSG00000155657.24 gene_biotype:protein_coding transcript_biotype:protein_coding gene_symbol:TTN description:titin [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:12403]
GCAGTCGTGCATTCCCAGCCTCGCCTCGGGTGTAGGGATTGCATAGAAAAGCAAAACTAC
ACAGTCTTGACTGTGTAGTTTTGTTTTTAGGATTAGAGGCTCACCGATTCATGTCGGAGA
TGGTCAGAAAAACCAACTCTCCATAGGACGTCGTTTCAGAAGCAACCTTGGGCTTAGTCC
CACCCTTTTTAGGCACTCTTGAGAAATCAGAGTGCCTAGAAAGATGACAACTCAAGCACC
GACGTTTACGCAGCCGTTACAAAGCGTTGTGGTACTGGAGGGTAGTACCGCAACCTTTGA
GGCTCACATTAGTGGTTTTCCAGTTCCTGAGGTGAGCTGGTTTAGGGATGGCCAGGTGAT
TTCCACTTCCACTCTGCCCGGCGTGCAGATCTCCTTTAGCGATGGCCGCGCTAAACTGAC
GATCCCCGCCGTGACTAAAGCCAACAGTGGACGATATTCCCTGAAAGCCACCAATGGATC
TGGACAAGCGACTAGTACTGCTGAGCTTCTCGTGAAAGCTGAGACAGCACCACCCAACTT
CGTTCAACGACTGCAGAGCATGACCGTGAGACAAGGAAGCCAAGTGAGACTCCAAGTGAG
AGTGACTGGAATCCCTACACCTGTGGTGAAGTTCTACCGGGATGGAGCCGAAATCCAGAG
CTCCCTTGATTTCCAAATTTCACAAGAAGGCGACCTCTACAGCTTACTGATTGCAGAAGC
ATACCCTGAGGACTCAGGGACCTATTCAGTAAATGCCACCAATAGCGTTGGAAGAGCTAC
TTCGACTGCTGAATTACTGGTTCAAGGTGAAGAAGAAGTACCTGCTAAAAAGACAAAGAC
AATTGTTTCGACTGCTCAGATCTCAGAATCAAGACAAACCCGAATTGAAAAGAAGATTGA
AGCCCACTTTGATGCCAGATCAATTGCAACAGTTGAGATGGTCATAGATGGTGCCGCTGG
GCAACAGCTGCCACATAAAACACCTCCCAGGATTCCTCCGAAGCCAAAGTCAAGATCCCC
AACACCACCGTCTATTGCTGCCAAAGCACAGCTGGCTCGGCAGCAGTCCCCATCGCCCAT
AAGACACTCCCCTTCCCCGGTCAGACACGTGCGGGCACCGACCCCATCTCCGGTCAGGTC
CGTGTCTCCAGCAGCAAGAATCTCCACATCCCCCATCAGGTCTGTTAGGTCTCCATTGCT
CATGCGTAAGACTCAGGCATCCACCGTGGCCACAGGTCCTGAAGTGCCTCCCCCTTGGAA
GCAAGAGGGCTACGTGGCCTCCTCATCTGAGGCTGAGATGAGAGAGACAACGCTGACAAC
CTCTACTCAGATCAGGACAGAAGAGAGATGGGAAGGGAGATACGGTGTCCAGGAGCAAGT
GACCATCAGTGGTGCTGCGGGTGCTGCCGCCAGTGTGTCGGCCAGTGCTAGCTACGCAGC
AGAGGCTGTTGCCACTGGTGCTAAAGAGGTGAAACAAGATGCTGACAAAAGTGCAGCTGT
TGCGACTGTTGTTGCTGCCGTTGATATGGCCAGAGTGAGAGAACCAGTGATCAGCGCTGT
AGAGCAGACTGCTCAGAGGACAACCACGACTGCTGTGCACATCCAACCTGCTCAAGAACA
GGTAAGAAAGGAAGCGGAGAAGACTGCTGTAACTAAGGTAGTAGTGGCCGCCGATAAAGC
CAAGGAACAAGAATTAAAATCAAGAACCAAAGAAGTAATTACCACAAAGCAAGAGCAGAT
GCACGTAACTCATGAGCAGATAAGAAAAGAAACTGAAAAAACATTTGTACCAAAGGTAGT
AATTTCCGCAGCTAAAGCCAAAGAACAAGAAACTAGAATTTCTGAAGAAATTACTAAGAA
ACAGAAACAAGTAACTCAAGAAGCAATAAGACAGGAAACTGAGATAACTGCTGCATCCAT
GGTGGTAGTTGCCACTGCAAAGTCCACAAAACTAGAAACAGTCCCGGGAGCTCAAGAAGA
AACTACCACACAACAAGATCAAATGCACCTAAGTTATGAAAAGATAATGAAGGAAACTAG
GAAAACAGTTGTACCTAAAGTCATAGTTGCCACACCCAAAGTCAAAGAACAAGATTTAGT
>ENST00000436599.1 cdna:known chromosome:GRCh38:2:178786089:178794954:-1 gene:ENSG00000155657.24 gene_biotype:protein_coding transcript_biotype:protein_coding gene_symbol:TTN description:titin [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:12403]
>ENST00000470257.1 cdna:known chromosome:GRCh38:2:178798495:178807408:-1 gene:ENSG00000155657.24 gene_biotype:protein_coding transcript_biotype:retained_intron gene_symbol:TTN description:titin [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:12403]
>ENST00000412264.1 cdna:known chromosome:GRCh38:2:178802287:178830802:-1 gene:ENSG00000155657.24 gene_biotype:protein_coding transcript_biotype:protein_coding gene_symbol:TTN description:titin [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:12403]
GCAGTCGTGCATTCCCAGCCTCGCCTCGGGTGTAGGGATTGCATAGAAAAGCAAAACTAC
ACAGTCTTGACTGTGTAGTTTTGTTTTTAGGATTAGAGGCTCACCGATTCATGTCGGAGA
TGGTCAGAAAAACCAACTCTCCATAGGACGTCGTTTCAGAAGCAACCTTGGGCTTAGTCC
CACCCTTTTTAGGCACTCTTGAGAAATCAGAGTGCCTAGAAAGATGACAACTCAAGCACC
GACGTTTACGCAGCCGTTACAAAGCGTTGTGGTACTGGAGGGTAGTACCGCAACCTTTGA
GGCTCACATTAGTGGTTTTCCAGTTCCTGAGGTGAGCTGGTTTAGGGATGGCCAGGTGAT
TTCCACTTCCACTCTGCCCGGCGTGCAGATCTCCTTTAGCGATGGCCGCGCTAAACTGAC
GATCCCCGCCGTGACTAAAGCCAACAGTGGACGATATTCCCTGAAAGCCACCAATGGATC
TGGACAAGCGACTAGTACTGCTGAGCTTCTCGTGAAAGCTGAGACAGCACCACCCAACTT
CGTTCAACGACTGCAGAGCATGACCGTGAGACAAGGAAGCCAAGTGAGACTCCAAGTGAG
AGTGACTGGAATCCCTACACCTGTGGTGAAGTTCTACCGGGATGGAGCCGAAATCCAGAG
CTCCCTTGATTTCCAAATTTCACAAGAAGGCGACCTCTACAGCTTACTGATTGCAGAAGC
ATACCCTGAGGACTCAGGGACCTATTCAGTAAATGCCACCAATAGCGTTGGAAGAGCTAC
TTCGACTGCTGAATTACTGGTTCAAGGTGAAGAAGAAGTACCTGCTAAAAAGACAAAGAC
AATTGTTTCGACTGCTCAGATCTCAGAATCAAGACAAACCCGAATTGAAAAGAAGATTGA
AGCCCACTTTGATGCCAGATCAATTGCAACAGTTGAGATGGTCATAGATGGTGCCGCTGG
GCAACAGCTGCCACATAAAACACCTCCCAGGATTCCTCCGAAGCCAAAGTCAAGATCCCC
AACACCACCGTCTATTGCTGCCAAAGCACAGCTGGCTCGGCAGCAGTCCCCATCGCCCAT
AAGACACTCCCCTTCCCCGGTCAGACACGTGCGGGCACCGACCCCATCTCCGGTCAGGTC
CGTGTCTCCAGCAGCAAGAATCTCCACATCCCCCATCAGGTCTGTTAGGTCTCCATTGCT
CATGCGTAAGACTCAGGCATCCACCGTGGCCACAGGTCCTGAAGTGCCTCCCCCTTGGAA
GCAAGAGGGCTACGTGGCCTCCTCATCTGAGGCTGAGATGAGAGAGACAACGCTGACAAC
CTCTACTCAGATCAGGACAGAAGAGAGATGGGAAGGGAGATACGGTGTCCAGGAGCAAGT
GACCATCAGTGGTGCTGCGGGTGCTGCCGCCAGTGTGTCGGCCAGTGCTAGCTACGCAGC
AGAGGCTGTTGCCACTGGTGCTAAAGAGGTGAAACAAGATGCTGACAAAAGTGCAGCTGT
TGCGACTGTTGTTGCTGCCGTTGATATGGCCAGAGTGAGAGAACCAGTGATCAGCGCTGT
AGAGCAGACTGCTCAGAGGACAACCACGACTGCTGTGCACATCCAACCTGCTCAAGAACA
GGTAAGAAAGGAAGCGGAGAAGACTGCTGTAACTAAGGTAGTAGTGGCCGCCGATAAAGC
CAAGGAACAAGAATTAAAATCAAGAACCAAAGAAGTAATTACCACAAAGCAAGAGCAGAT
GCACGTAACTCATGAGCAGATAAGAAAAGAAACTGAAAAAACATTTGTACCAAAGGTAGT
AATTTCCGCAGCTAAAGCCAAAGAACAAGAAACTAGAATTTCTGAAGAAATTACTAAGAA
ACAGAAACAAGTAACTCAAGAAGCAATAAGACAGGAAACTGAGATAACTGCTGCATCCAT
GGTGGTAGTTGCCACTGCAAAGTCCACAAAACTAGAAACAGTCCCGGGAGCTCAAGAAGA
AACTACCACACAACAAGATCAAATGCACCTAAGTTATGAAAAGATAATGAAGGAAACTAG
GAAAACAGTTGTACCTAAAGTCATAGTTGCCACACCCAAAGTCAAAGAACAAGATTTAGT
>ENST00000359218.9 cdna:known chromosome:GRCh38:2:178525989:178807423:-1 gene:ENSG00000155657.24 gene_biotype:protein_coding transcript_biotype:protein_coding gene_symbol:TTN description:titin [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:12403]
GCAGTCGTGCATTCCCAGCCTCGCCTCGGGTGTAGGGATTGCATAGAAAAGCAAAACTAC
ACAGTCTTGACTGTGTAGTTTTGTTTTTAGGATTAGAGGCTCACCGATTCATGTCGGAGA
TGGTCAGAAAAACCAACTCTCCATAGGACGTCGTTTCAGAAGCAACCTTGGGCTTAGTCC
CACCCTTTTTAGGCACTCTTGAGAAATCAGAGTGCCTAGAAAGATGACAACTCAAGCACC
GACGTTTACGCAGCCGTTACAAAGCGTTGTGGTACTGGAGGGTAGTACCGCAACCTTTGA
GGCTCACATTAGTGGTTTTCCAGTTCCTGAGGTGAGCTGGTTTAGGGATGGCCAGGTGAT
TTCCACTTCCACTCTGCCCGGCGTGCAGATCTCCTTTAGCGATGGCCGCGCTAAACTGAC
GATCCCCGCCGTGACTAAAGCCAACAGTGGACGATATTCCCTGAAAGCCACCAATGGATC
TGGACAAGCGACTAGTACTGCTGAGCTTCTCGTGAAAGCTGAGACAGCACCACCCAACTT
CGTTCAACGACTGCAGAGCATGACCGTGAGACAAGGAAGCCAAGTGAGACTCCAAGTGAG
AGTGACTGGAATCCCTACACCTGTGGTGAAGTTCTACCGGGATGGAGCCGAAATCCAGAG
CTCCCTTGATTTCCAAATTTCACAAGAAGGCGACCTCTACAGCTTACTGATTGCAGAAGC
ATACCCTGAGGACTCAGGGACCTATTCAGTAAATGCCACCAATAGCGTTGGAAGAGCTAC
TTCGACTGCTGAATTACTGGTTCAAGGTGAAGAAGAAGTACCTGCTAAAAAGACAAAGAC
AATTGTTTCGACTGCTCAGATCTCAGAATCAAGACAAACCCGAATTGAAAAGAAGATTGA
AGCCCACTTTGATGCCAGATCAATTGCAACAGTTGAGATGGTCATAGATGGTGCCGCTGG
GCAACAGCTGCCACATAAAACACCTCCCAGGATTCCTCCGAAGCCAAAGTCAAGATCCCC
AACACCACCGTCTATTGCTGCCAAAGCACAGCTGGCTCGGCAGCAGTCCCCATCGCCCAT
AAGACACTCCCCTTCCCCGGTCAGACACGTGCGGGCACCGACCCCATCTCCGGTCAGGTC
CGTGTCTCCAGCAGCAAGAATCTCCACATCCCCCATCAGGTCTGTTAGGTCTCCATTGCT
CATGCGTAAGACTCAGGCATCCACCGTGGCCACAGGTCCTGAAGTGCCTCCCCCTTGGAA
GCAAGAGGGCTACGTGGCCTCCTCATCTGAGGCTGAGATGAGAGAGACAACGCTGACAAC
CTCTACTCAGATCAGGACAGAAGAGAGATGGGAAGGGAGATACGGTGTCCAGGAGCAAGT
GACCATCAGTGGTGCTGCGGGTGCTGCCGCCAGTGTGTCGGCCAGTGCTAGCTACGCAGC
AGAGGCTGTTGCCACTGGTGCTAAAGAGGTGAAACAAGATGCTGACAAAAGTGCAGCTGT
TGCGACTGTTGTTGCTGCCGTTGATATGGCCAGAGTGAGAGAACCAGTGATCAGCGCTGT
AGAGCAGACTGCTCAGAGGACAACCACGACTGCTGTGCACATCCAACCTGCTCAAGAACA
GGTAAGAAAGGAAGCGGAGAAGACTGCTGTAACTAAGGTAGTAGTGGCCGCCGATAAAGC
CAAGGAACAAGAATTAAAATCAAGAACCAAAGAAGTAATTACCACAAAGCAAGAGCAGAT
GCACGTAACTCATGAGCAGATAAGAAAAGAAACTGAAAAAACATTTGTACCAAAGGTAGT
AATTTCCGCAGCTAAAGCCAAAGAACAAGAAACTAGAATTTCTGAAGAAATTACTAAGAA
ACAGAAACAAGTAACTCAAGAAGCAATAAGACAGGAAACTGAGATAACTGCTGCATCCAT
GGTGGTAGTTGCCACTGCAAAGTCCACAAAACTAGAAACAGTCCCGGGAGCTCAAGAAGA
AACTACCACACAACAAGATCAAATGCACCTAAGTTATGAAAAGATAATGAAGGAAACTAG
GAAAACAGTTGTACCTAAAGTCATAGTTGCCACACCCAAAGTCAAAGAACAAGATTTAGT
```

The headerlist.txt file looks exactly like:

```
ENST00000342992.10
ENST00000460472.6
ENST00000589042.5
ENST00000591111.5
ENST00000359218.9
ENST00000615779.4
ENST00000342175.10
```

I have written awk code that collects headers I would like to target, and collect that header along with its following information until next header.

---

I call it with:

```
awk -f myScript.txt <headerlist.txt> <informationfile.txt>
```

Below is the code:

```
#!/bin/awk                       
NR == FNR {tags[$1]; next;}
for (i in tags) { if (i ~ $0) {a=1; print; next;}}
/>/ {a=0}
a
```

It should produce:

```
>Target Header
Information attached to header
.
.
.
```

However, I am getting a syntax error with no information to it. The arrow does not point to any character just blank space.

```
^ Syntax Error
```

How would I correct this?

Comment: move `for (i in tags)` inside the curly brace.

Comment: Its running. :) - However, it is producing no output.

Comment: well, it fixes the syntax error.  there are other issues with your script, for example what is the intended use of `a`?

Comment: I am using 'a' as a placement for 'print $0'

Comment: OK, it wasn't there before.  please see my updated answer.

Comment: Get rid of all the dots and instead populate your sample input/output with some actual representative values. Without concise, testable sample input and expected output its much harder for us to help you.

Comment: Updating with actual values

Comment: Be sure to include sample contents of BOTH input files, <headerlist.txt> and <informationfile.txt>

Comment: It has been updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Input**

```
$ cat HeaderList
Target Header
SomeOther Header

$ cat InfoFile
>Generic Header
Information attached to header
.
.
.
>Target Header
Information attached to header
.
.
.
>SomeOther Header
Information attached to header
.
.
.
```

**Script**

```
  while read line
  do 
  awk 'BEGIN{RS="\n>"}/'"$line"'/{printf ">%s\n",$0}' InfoFile
  done <HeaderList
```

**Output**

```
>Target Header
Information attached to header
.
.
.
>SomeOther Header
Information attached to header
.
.
.
```

Comment: How would I go about using multiple "Target Headers"?

Comment: @NicholasHayden : Updated.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will be a better solution

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{h[$0]; next} 
       $0 in h{c=2} 
        c&&c--' headers file

>Target Header
Information attached to header
```

if your headers are exactly the same you can match with equality check ($0 in h) and print the two lines.

If you want to print until the next header

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{h[$0]; next} 
          /^>/{p=0} 
       $0 in h{p=1} 
              p' headers file

>Target Header
Information attached to header
.
.
.
```

With the new file layout this script needs to be modified as such

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{h[">"$0]; next} 
          /^>/{p=0} 
       $1 in h{p=1} 
              p' headers file
```

as long as there is a white space between the key (used in headers file) and the rest of the record this should work.  Now, headers won't have the ">" prefix.

Comment: I ran your code and it is not producing an output. Could you elaborate with the equality check?

Comment: I used your input file exactly and the headers file containing ">Target Header".  This checks whether any line in the file is in `h` (populated from headers file).  To test copy the text from the Question to a file and create headers file with `echo ">Target Header" > headers` and run the `awk` script.

Comment: I am trying to replicate your output and I am not succeeding. I have used my provided input, and tried to your code exactly.

Comment: how about the header file?

Comment: It's probably the `>` is missing from the header file or something.... We'll know once the OP updates the question with some real values.